# closed form for $\sum_{n\geq1}\pi n\log\frac{4n+1}{4n-1}\prod_{k\geq1\\k\neq n}\frac{k^2}{k^2-n^2}$?

Tags: integration, closed-form, alternative-proof

Look at what I found!
$$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}x\csc x\ \mathrm dx=\sum_{n\geq1}\pi n\log\bigg(\frac{4n+1}{4n-1}\bigg)\prod_{k\geq1\\k\neq n}\frac{k^2}{k^2-n^2}$$
I want to know if it is valid, and if there is a nice closed form to go with my series.

Here's my proof.

Recall the famous product representation
$$\sin x=x\prod_{k\geq1}\bigg(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2k^2}\bigg)$$
Hence we have that 
$$I=\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}x\csc x\ \mathrm dx=\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\prod_{k\geq1}\frac{\pi^2k^2}{\pi^2k^2-x^2}\mathrm dx$$
We may now preform a fraction decomposition, and start with 
$$\prod_{k\geq1}\frac{\pi^2k^2}{\pi^2k^2-x^2}=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\pi^2n^2}{\pi^2n^2-x^2}b_n$$ 
Multiplying both sides by $\prod_{k\geq1}\frac{\pi^2k^2-x^2}{\pi^2k^2}$,
$$1=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\pi^2n^2}{\pi^2n^2-x^2}b_n\prod_{k\geq1}\frac{\pi^2k^2-x^2}{\pi^2k^2}$$
$$1=\sum_{n\geq1}b_n\prod_{k\geq1\\k\neq n}\frac{\pi^2k^2-x^2}{\pi^2k^2}$$
Which in turn implies that, for any $m\in\Bbb N$,
$$1=b_m\prod_{k\geq1\\k\neq m}\frac{\pi^2k^2-\pi^2m^2}{\pi^2k^2}$$
$$b_m=\prod_{k\geq1\\k\neq m}\frac{k^2}{k^2-m^2}$$
Hence we can begin the process of integration:
$$I=\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\pi^2n^2}{\pi^2n^2-x^2}b_n\mathrm dx$$
$$I=\sum_{n\geq1}\pi^2n^2b_n\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\pi^2n^2-x^2}$$
This final integral evaluates to 
$$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\pi^2n^2-x^2}=\frac1{\pi n}\log\bigg(\frac{4n+1}{4n-1}\bigg)$$
So finally we have 
$$I=\sum_{n\geq1}\pi n\log\bigg(\frac{4n+1}{4n-1}\bigg)\prod_{k\geq1\\k\neq n}\frac{k^2}{k^2-n^2}$$
Does this work? Is there a closed form value for $I$? Is there another way to prove this?

**Update:**

Integrating form $0$ to $\pi/2$ instead of $-\pi/4$ to $\pi/4$ gives, according to Wolfram Alpha,
$$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\pi n}2\log\bigg(\frac{2n+1}{2n-1}\bigg)\prod_{k\geq1\\k\neq n}\frac{k^2}{k^2-n^2}=2G$$
Where $G$ is Catalan's constant. Isn't that cool?! That's crazy cool!

Comment: Yes it _is_ 'crazy-cool' ... & there are lirerally _thousands_ of crazy-cool results like that! I can't get enough of 'em.